# How to submit error free form

Tags: php

Being a beginner, I am at a cross road on how to submit an error free form. Reference to the php file below, I have used 3 action settings with the following consequence:
Method 1 
action = ""
This indicates the errors on same page whether there is an error or not.
Method 2:
action=""
This indicates the errors on same page whether there is an error or not.
Method 3:
action="User sch contact.php"
This opens a new page (User sch contact) with all the user input whether there is error or not.

Now I do not want the form submitted until every error is cleared by the user. Please how can I achieve this? Is there anything I am missing in php, sql, Mysql that will help me achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Exercise</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica,Sans-serif; padding: 0px;   
margin-left: 50px;}
input:hover {background-color: rgb(250,250,150);}
.btn {padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; background-color: rgb(240,240,240); font-  
size: 12px; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; border: 1px; }
.btn:hover {background-color: rgb(250,250,150);}
th {font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; border-style: solid;   
margin: 0px; border-spacing: 0px;}
.cdtl {text-align: left;}
td {font-weight: Normal; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; border-style: solid;   
margin: 0px; border-spacing: 0px;}
.err {color: rgb(250,50,10); width: 200px; font-style: italic; border: 0px;   
font-size: 14px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var debugScript = true;
</script>

</head>
```

```
   <?php
    $username = $useraddy1 = $useraddy2 = $userfone = $useremail = $userurl   
    = "";
    $firstgrade = $secondgrade = $thirdgrade = $fourthgrade = "";
    $usernameerr = $useraddy1err = $useraddy2err = $userfoneerr = 
    $useremailerr = $userurlerr = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $usernameerr = "Name is required";
    } else {
    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$username)) {
    $usernameerr = "Only alphanumerics and white space allowed";
    } else {$usernameerr = "";}
        }

    if (empty($_POST["useraddy1"])) {
    $useraddy1err = "Address is required";
    } else {
    $useraddy1 = test_input($_POST["useraddy1"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$useraddy1)) {
    $useraddy1err = "Only alphanumerics and white space allowed";
    } else {$useraddy1err = "";}
        }

    if (empty($_POST["useraddy2"])) {
    $useraddy2err = "Address is required";
    } else {
    $useraddy2 = test_input($_POST["useraddy2"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$useraddy2)) {
    $useraddy2err = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    } else {$useraddy2err = "";}
        }

    if (empty($_POST["userfone"])) {
    $userfoneerr = "Address is required";
    } else {
    $userfone = test_input($_POST["userfone"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[+0-9]*$/",$userfone)) {
    $userfoneerr = "Only + numbers and white space allowed";
    } else {$userfoneerr = "";}
        }

   if (empty($_POST["useremail"])) {
    $useremailerr = "Email is required";
    } else {
    $useremail = test_input($_POST["useremail"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($useremail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $useremailerr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["userurl"])) {
    $userurl = "";
    } else {
    $userurl = test_input($_POST["userurl"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also 
    allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?
    =~_|!:,.;]* [-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$userurl)) {
    $userurlerr = "Invalid URL"; 
            }
        }
    }
    function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
        }
    ?>

<h4>User Input</h4>
<form  id="setUp" method="post" action="<?php echo  
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<table id="contact" class="userInfo">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">User Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name='username' value="<?php echo $username;?>" /> 
</td>
<td class='err'><?php echo $usernameerr;?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Address1:Number, Street, City</td>
<td><input type="text" name='useraddy1' value="<?php echo $useraddy1;?>" />    
</td>
<td class='err'><?php echo $useraddy1err;?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Address2:State, Country</td>
<td><input type="text" name='useraddy2' value="<?php echo $useraddy2;?>" />
</td>
<td class='err'><?php echo $useraddy2err;?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Telephone (International format)</td>
<td><input type="text" name='userfone' value="<?php echo $userfone;?>" />   
</td>
<td class='err'><?php echo $userfoneerr;?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">e-mail Address</td>
<td><input type="email" name='useremail' value="<?php echo $useremail;?>" />   
</td>
<td class='err'><?php echo $useremailerr;?></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Website (Optional)</td>
<td><input type="url" name='userurl' value="<?php echo $userurl;?>" /></td>
<td class='err'><?php echo $userurlerr;?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input  class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: When I use  action="User sch contact.php", the file opens with all data inputted by the user even when there are strange characters in the form fields. e.g. If the user input $, #, @ in the name field, I dont expect the form to be submitted because this is an error which should be captured by the script.

Comment: this line of your code works? if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$username)) { because here you only allow letters and numbers

Comment: Note that if I set the action="", the page will indicate  such error and will not submit the form. So how can I run event.preventDefault() when there is such error. Thank you

Comment: All the lines work fine. The main challenge is how to prevent submit when there is an error in user input

Comment: Ok, now I understand your question, did you try using jquery and ajax implementation?

Comment: I do a little example to how to prevent a submit if an input is empty, you could add your another if in javascript code. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/8s5jfxz0/ it is very simple to understand, I am using jQuery that is javascript

Answer (score 0):

I have resubmitted this question in a different way. Basically, I was trying to validate a form on the client side. The best approach is to use both required and pattern in the input. With these 2, the form will not be submitted with a blank field & if user input does not follow the pattern. Further validation will of course be done on the server side for double assurance.

```
<form>
<b>User Id:<b><br>
<input id="userid" name="userid" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-
z0-9.-_]{5,10}"><br>
<b>Password:<b><br>
<input id="userpswd" name="userpswd" type="password" required 
pattern="[A-Za-z0-9&*]{8,20}"><br><br>
<b>SS Level:<b><br>
<input id="sslevel" name="sslevel" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]
{3,8}">
<input id='submit' type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```